# jQuery and Dynamitable library

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I am using this lib: https://github.com/Dynamitable/Dynamitable

It's pretty nice, and it works perfectly for me, for now.

When I'm trying to filter it (like filter "name" when I'm typing "abc" on the input field) all rows are dissapearing in order to show me every "name" rown which contains "abc. So this is nice !

My problem is, I'm using a very big table, and the filter works "too" good for me. I mean, I can't type my entire "research" before it start working.

So, my question is, is it possible to add a "delay", in order to let people type some letter before starting filtering ? Something like 0.5 sec or even 1 sec ?

I had try to play with this on line 150/153, but no success :

```html
$(selector).on('change keyup keydown', filterAction);
            
// initialization
filterAction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is to disconnect the original filters and add your own filter with the capability to start the filtering only after n char.

In the following an example:

```js
$('.js-dynamitable .js-filter').off('change keyup keydown').on('change keyup keydown', function (e) {
    //
    // start filtering on text input only after 2 chars
    //
    if ($(this).is(':text') && $(this).val().length < 2) {
        return;  // stop filtering
    }
    var index = $(this).closest('tr').children('td, th').index($(this).closest('td, th'));
    var dynamitable = $('.js-dynamitable').dynamitable();
    dynamitable.displayAll();
    $(dynamitable).find('.js-filter').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        dynamitable.filter(index, $this.val());
    });
});
```

```css
.glyphicon {
    cursor: pointer;
}

input, select {
    width: 100%;
}

.second, .glyphicon-chevron-down, .glyphicon-chevron-up {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Dynamitable/Dynamitable/master/dynamitable.jquery.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-10  col-lg-offset-1">
    <h1><span class="first">Dynami</span><span class="second">table</span></h1>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="js-dynamitable     table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name
                    <span class="js-sorter-desc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                    <span class="js-sorter-asc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
                </th>
                <th>Email
                    <span class="js-sorter-desc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                    <span class="js-sorter-asc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
                </th>
                <th>Age
                    <span class="js-sorter-desc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                    <span class="js-sorter-asc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
                </th>
                <th>Account
                    <span class="js-sorter-desc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                    <span class="js-sorter-asc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
                </th>
                <th>Scoring
                    <span class="js-sorter-desc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                    <span class="js-sorter-asc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input class="js-filter  form-control" type="text" value="">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <select class="js-filter  form-control">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="@dynamitable.com">dynamitable.com</option>
                        <option value="@sample.com">Sample</option>
                    </select>
                </th>
                <th><input class="js-filter  form-control" type="text" value=""></th>
                <th><input class="js-filter  form-control" type="text" value=""></th>
                <th><input class="js-filter  form-control" type="text" value=""></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Freddy Krueger</td>
                <td>freddy.krueger@sample.com</td>
                <td class="text-right">122</td>
                <td class="text-right">2300$</td>
                <td class="text-right">+15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Clint Eastwood</td>
                <td>clint.eastwood@sample.com</td>
                <td class="text-right">62</td>
                <td class="text-right">48 500$</td>
                <td class="text-right">+12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Peter Parker</td>
                <td>peter.parker@dynamitable.com</td>
                <td class="text-right">22</td>
                <td class="text-right">210$</td>
                <td class="text-right">-5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruce Wayne</td>
                <td>bruce.wayne@dynamitable.com</td>
                <td class="text-right">42</td>
                <td class="text-right">-8500$</td>
                <td class="text-right">+2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackie Chan</td>
                <td>jackie.chan@sample.com</td>
                <td class="text-right">32</td>
                <td class="text-right">-250.55$</td>
                <td class="text-right">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruce Lee</td>
                <td>bruce.lee@sample.com</td>
                <td class="text-right">32</td>
                <td class="text-right">510$</td>
                <td class="text-right">-7</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess it's a good idea to manage the number of character instead of time... So stupid to not thought about that. :/