# Exact match with Dynamitable library

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have a question with https://github.com/Dynamitable/Dynamitable.

When I try to filter results, it doesn't bring up the exact matches. For example, when I type 1 in the filter box, it brings all values including 1. Is it possible to make it show only the exact number when I try to filter?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show us your code you have tried

Comment: I didn't try anything. This is a free code available, I searched for it, but I couldn't find much information on this project. there is just one question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646555/jquery-and-dynamitable-library

Comment: Well the demo works fine, look at the age and try your filter there, its working

Comment: Did you try with one digit number? the problem is with one digits.

Comment: Yes i did, i wrote 1, 2 and 32 and all of them works

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-column-Table-Sorting-Filtering-Dynamitable/ when you type 2 in scoring filter on this link, it shows numbers including 2.

Comment: Yes is shows +12 and +2, is that wrong, what do you want it to show ?

Comment: If I type 2, I just want to see the values 2. not all the values with 2.

Comment: aha, the library search those column as string. that mean `"+12".indexOf("2") != -1` if you want it to work like you want then you have to identify those values as int and decimal. so you have to rewrite the filter mikanism, in the library. But i think that its working like it should be. i could understand you requirement if you said thet you would like a search like this >2 then i could understand.

Comment: It's a nice library, but I doesn't fit my needs exactly unfortunately.

Comment: its easy to rewrite the the search mikanism. you wont find any library that works how you like without changing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i changed the library and added the exact match function you wanted. 
look at the score filter input, i added an attribute searchType="exact" it will search for exact match for those input that containe this attribute

The change made this in this.filter

```
  this.filter = function filter(index, matches, searchType) {
       if (searchType != "exact" || matches.length<=0 )
       {        
        var regex = new RegExp(matches, 'i');
        dynamitableCore.getRows().each(function () {
            if(true !== regex.test(dynamitableCore.getValue(index, $(this)))) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });

       }else {
            // added this
            dynamitableCore.getRows().each(function () {
            var v = dynamitableCore.getValue(index, $(this));
            if(v != matches) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });

       }
        return this;
    };
```

```js
!function($){ 'use strict';

    $.fn.dynamitable = function(options) {
    
        /**********************************************
         * dynamitable
         **********************************************/
        var dynamitable = this;
        
        /**********************************************
         * dynamitableCore
         **********************************************/
        var dynamitableCore = new (function($dynamitable) {
        
            /**********************************************
             * dynamitableCore.getIndex($field)
             *
             * get the index of a field
             *
             * return integer
             **********************************************/
            this.getIndex = function($field) {
                return $field.parents('tr').children('td, th').index($field);
            };
            
            /**********************************************
             * dynamitableCore.getBody()
             *
             * get the body of the table
             *
             * return dom
             **********************************************/
            this.getBody = function() {
                return $dynamitable.find('tbody');
            };
            
            /**********************************************
             * dynamitableCore.getRows()
             *
             * get all row inside the body of the table
             *
             * return dom
             **********************************************/
            this.getRows = function() {
                return this.getBody().children('tr');
            };
            
            /**********************************************
             * dynamitableCore.getField(index, $row)
             *
             * get a field
             *
             * return dom
             **********************************************/
            this.getField = function(index, $row) {
                return $row.children('td, th').eq(index);
            };
            
            /**********************************************
             * dynamitableCore.getValue(index, $row)
             *
             * get a field value
             *
             * return string
             **********************************************/
            this.getValue = function(index, $row) {
                return this.getField(index, $row).text();
            };
            
        })($(this));   
        
        /**********************************************
         * dynamitable.filterList
         *
         * list of filter selector
         *
         * array of string
         **********************************************/
        this.filterList = [];
        
        /**********************************************
         * dynamitable.displayAll()
         *
         * show all <tr>
         *
         * return dynamitable
         **********************************************/
        this.displayAll = function() {

            dynamitableCore.getRows().each(function() {
                $(this).show();
            });
          
            return this;
        };

        /**********************************************
         * dynamitable.filter(index, matches)
         *
         * hide all <tr> that doen't martch
         *
         * - index (integer): index of the colum to filter
         * - matches (string)  : string to search on the colum
         *
         * return dynamitable
         **********************************************/
        this.filter = function filter(index, matches, searchType) {
           if (searchType != "exact" || matches.length<=0 )
     {  
            var regex = new RegExp(matches, 'i');
            dynamitableCore.getRows().each(function () {
                if(true !== regex.test(dynamitableCore.getValue(index, $(this)))) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
          
     }else {
      
                dynamitableCore.getRows().each(function () {
       var v = dynamitableCore.getValue(index, $(this));
                if(v != matches) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
      
     }
            return this;
        };
        
        /**********************************************
         * dynamitable.addFilter(selector)
         *
         * add filter event on element inside the table heading
         *
         * - selector (string) : selector of the element that trigger the event
         *
         * return dynamitable
         **********************************************/
        this.addFilter = function addFilter(selector) {
        
            // add the selector on the filter list
            dynamitable.filterList.push(selector);
            
            // the filter
            var filterAction = function() {
            
                 dynamitable.displayAll();
                 
                 $(dynamitable.filterList).each(function(index, selector) {
                 
                    $(dynamitable).find(selector).each(function() {
                        var $this =  $(this);
      var searchType = $this.attr("searchType"); // eg string or decimal
                        dynamitable.filter(dynamitableCore.getIndex($this.parent('td, th')), $this.val(), searchType);  
                    });
                 
                 });
            };
            
            // attach the filter action to the selector
            $(selector).on('change keyup keydown', filterAction);
            
            // initialization
            filterAction();
            
            return this;
        }; 
        
        /**********************************************
         * dynamitable.addSorter(selector, order)
         *
         * add soter event on element inside the table heading
         *
         * - selector (string) : selector of the element that trigger the event
         * - order (string) :  sorting order [asc, desc]
         *
         * return dynamitable
         **********************************************/
        this.addSorter = function addSorter(selector, order) {

            $(dynamitable).find(selector).each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                
                var index = dynamitableCore.getIndex($this.parent('td, th'));
                
                $this.on('click', function() { dynamitable.sorter(index, order); });
            });
            
            return this;
        }; 
    
        /**********************************************
         * dynamitable.sorter(index, order)
         *
         * - index (integer): index of the colum to sorter
         * - order (string)  : sorting order [asc, desc]
         *
         * return dynamitable
         **********************************************/
        this.sorter = function sorter(index, order) {

           dynamitableCore.getBody().append(dynamitableCore.getRows().detach().sort(function(row_a, row_b) {

                var value_a = dynamitableCore.getValue(index, $(row_a));
                var value_b = dynamitableCore.getValue(index, $(row_b));
                
                var order_desc = ('desc' === order) ? true : false;
                
                // numeric order mode
                if(value_a.replace(/[^\d-]/g, '') !== '' && value_b.replace(/[^\d-]/g, '') !== '') {
                    value_a = parseFloat(value_a.replace(/[^\d,.\-\+]/g, ''));
                    value_b = parseFloat(value_b.replace(/[^\d,.\-\+]/g, ''));
                }
                
                if(value_a === value_b) {
                    return 0;
                }

                return (value_a > value_b) ? order_desc ? 1 : -1 : order_desc ? -1 : 1;

            }));
            
            return this;
        };
          
        return this;
    };
    
    /**********************************************
     * Dynamitable trigger
     **********************************************/
    $(document).find('.js-dynamitable').each(function(){
    
        $(this).dynamitable()
            .addFilter('.js-filter')
            .addSorter('.js-sorter-asc', 'asc')
            .addSorter('.js-sorter-desc', 'desc')
        ;
    });

}(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Dynamitable</title>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            <!--
            .glyphicon {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            
            input, select{
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            .second, .glyphicon-chevron-down, .glyphicon-chevron-up{
                color: red;
            }

            -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-10  col-lg-offset-1">
        
            <h1><span class="first">Dynami</span><span class="second">table</span></h1>
            
            <div class="table-responsive">
            
                <!-- Initialization 
                * js-dynamitable => dynamitable trigger (table)
                -->
                <table class="js-dynamitable     table table-bordered">
                    
                    <!-- table heading -->
                    <thead>
                    
                        <!-- Sortering
                        * js-sorter-asc => ascending sorter trigger
                        * js-sorter-desc => desending sorter trigger
                        -->
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name
                                <span class="js-sorter-desc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                                <span class="js-sorter-asc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
                             </th>
                            <th>Email
                                <span class="js-sorter-desc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                                <span class="js-sorter-asc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
                             </th>
                            <th>Age
                                <span class="js-sorter-desc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                                <span class="js-sorter-asc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
                             </th>
                            <th>Account
                                <span class="js-sorter-desc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                                <span class="js-sorter-asc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th>Scoring
                                <span class="js-sorter-desc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                                <span class="js-sorter-asc     glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <!-- Filtering
                        * js-filter => filter trigger (input, select)
                        -->
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <!-- input filter -->
                                <input  class="js-filter  form-control" type="text" value="">
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <!-- select filter -->
                                <select class="js-filter  form-control">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="@dynamitable.com">dynamitable.com</option>
                                    <option value="@sample.com">Sample</option>
                                </select>
                            </th>
                            <th><input class="js-filter  form-control" type="text" value=""></th>
                            <th><input class="js-filter  form-control" type="text" value=""></th>
                            <th><input class="js-filter  form-control" searchType="exact" type="text" value=""></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <!-- table body -->
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Freddy Krueger</td>
                            <td>freddy.krueger@sample.com</td>
                            <td class="text-right">122</td>
                            <td class="text-right">2300$</td>
                            <td class="text-right">+15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Clint Eastwood</td>
                            <td>clint.eastwood@sample.com</td>
                            <td class="text-right">62</td>
                            <td class="text-right">48 500$</td>
                            <td class="text-right">+12</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Peter Parker</td>
                            <td>peter.parker@dynamitable.com</td>
                            <td class="text-right">22</td>
                            <td class="text-right">210$</td>
                            <td class="text-right">-5</td>
                        </tr>  
                        <tr>
                            <td>Bruce Wayne</td> 
                            <td>bruce.wayne@dynamitable.com</td>                  
                            <td class="text-right">42</td>  
                            <td class="text-right">-8500$</td>         
                            <td class="text-right">+2</td>                        
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jackie Chan</td>
                            <td>jackie.chan@sample.com</td>
                            <td class="text-right">32</td>
                            <td class="text-right">-250.55$</td>
                            <td class="text-right">0</td>  
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                            <td>Bruce Lee</td>
                            <td>bruce.lee@sample.com</td>
                            <td class="text-right">32</td>
                            <td class="text-right">510$</td>
                            <td class="text-right">-7</td> 
                        </tr>
                         
                    </tbody>
                    
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- jquery -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- dynamitable -->
      
    </body>
</html>
```